# ¿cómo seleccionar todas las opciones de mat-select multiple en angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, material

:D

Estoy realizando un proyecto con Angular material. He colocado un botón que despliega un select múltiple, y lo que necesito es que por defecto aparezcan todas las opciones seleccionadas.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select placeholder="Equipos" multiple>
<mat-option *ngFor="let equipo of equipoList"> {{equipo.label}}</matoption>
</mat-select>
<mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo tienes puedes asignarle el array como value al `mat-select`

```
<mat-select placeholder="Equipos" multiple [value]="equipoList">
```

EDIT:

No me había fijado pero también te falta asignar el value de cada item en el `mat-option`

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let equipo of equipoList" [value]="equipo"> {{equipo.label}}</matoption>
```

un saludo

Comment: Buenas! Ante todo muchas gracias por la respuesta.

He probado lo que comentas pero no me funciona. Puede ser porque el array no viene cargado desde el inicio, sino que se rellena dinamicamente al pulsar un boton previo en función de unos filtros aplicados. 

Mi select multiple se abre al pulsar un botón, en el que he puesto una función que copia el array "equipolist" en un array vacio que pongo en el "value" de met-select. Pero sigue sin funcionar... Ya no sé que probar.

No existe alguna opción mas simple como un atributo para el option o similar? :/

Comment: @Juanlugos no me había fijado que no habías asignado la propiedad `value` en el`mat-option`, probablemente no te funcionara por eso. He editado la respuesta con lo que tienes que añadir. Pruébalo a ver si lo soluciona y sino añade por favor algo más del código afectado a ver si damos con ello. un saludo.

Comment: Así me ha funcionado perfecto al fin!!! Tengo ganas de llorar y todo jajajaja Muchísimas muchísimas gracias, no sabes ni la de vueltas que le he dado :DDD

Comment: un placer haberte podido ayudar. slds